# Angular: Can we update data of a local json file or the angular json-webserver data?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, dataservice

Situation : I'm using a data service in my project to get local json data then share it to multiple components. In part of my project, i have a component which is calling another component.
The first component is step component, this one get only data with type of steps from json to show them as angular material stepper.. The second one is form component which is responsible of getting each step data by stepId and the step name then load them in each step.
I want to add delete/add steps in step component and update data so the second component updates data too but when i do the data service isn't updating...
I was getting data from a local json file then i changed it and used "Angular json-webservice" but it's not working, here is the code :

```js
setControls (controls: IControl[]) {
    console.log('patch : ',controls)
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/controls',controls);
        
}
```

Question : How to update Angular json-server data in my data service ?
If not possible without backend should i pass the array from comp1 to comp2 ?
Or initializing an array list an fill it from json file, make the array public static and use it in all components until working on back-end ? (I'm a front-end developer only now)

Update : I followed @Inesa Toroyan reply and put the http.get data into an array in my data service and in my components i get that data array.
Adding a new step is working fine but the initial data aren't showing !
The FormGoup and the FormArray are getting the array just before it is filled with the data by http.get()
How to fix this ?

`Stepper Component` :

```js
public inputdataList:{}[]=[]
inputForm!: FormGroup;     
 
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder,private dataService:DataService ){
    
      this.inputdataList =this.dataService.getControls()
      this.inputForm = this.fb.group({
          inputs: this.fb.array(this.inputdataList) ,
          XXXXXXXXX : new FormControl('', Validators.required)      
      })
}
```

`Data Service` :

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  
    controls: IControl[] = [];
    private API_URL= environment.baseURL;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get<IControl[]>(this.API_URL+'controls').subscribe(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                this.controls = 
                JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).controls
            });;  
    }

    
    getControls () {
        return this.controls;     
    }
    
    setControls (controls: IControl[]) {
        console.log('patch : ',controls)
        this.controls = controls;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you doing the following.

- Mark your service to be injectable in root ( you will have a single instance for your components).
  For that, you need to add the following decorator to your class

`@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`

- Then, whenever you are getting your data in your service, store it to some private variable and create a getter,setter for it
- Afterwards, when you wish to edit your data in some component, then call the setter method in your component to modify the data. In your case, as you want to implement delete lets say, you need to use array methods of js such as filter, to edit your data.

Also, I would recommend you to change a bit this part -
`this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/controls',controls);`

You can add the `http://localhost:3000/controls` to your environment.ts file,because later changing it manually in many places will be a very inefficient task.

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseURL : "http://localhost:3000/"
};
```

If I got your question incorrectly, please make it more clear :))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation !
I added the URL in my environment.ts file, called baseURL variable in httpClient instead of the url string and it's working fine !!!
The decorator @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) in my data service is already added by default.
I also followed what you said, i stored data in a private array, when i add a step it's adding it to the data service  but the problem now is that the FormGroup and the FormArray are getting that data variable as a blank array, it means that they are getting the array just before it's filled with the http.get()

Comment: I will Update my question and add a part of the component code

Comment: I think you should edit this part.

`  this.http.get<IControl[]>(this.API_URL+'controls').subscribe(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response)
                this.controls = 
                JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).controls
            });;  ` .

Do not subscribe to the observable in the dataService, but use rxjs pipes to store the data whenever it will be there.